# get only file name while iterating over directory instead of path with it

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
$ script.sh -i /storage/testFile
```

`-i` stores the path of `/storage/testFile/`.

I want to iterate over file in `testFile`. Everything goes good, but I want to make this code cleaner and add a directory for output and other checks.

A snippet of my code is:

```
for f in $inDir/*.vcf; do
    if [ -f $f ]; #check if file is true or exists
    then
    if [   ${f: -4} == ".vcf" ] # check if the file ends with .vcf
        then
        convert2annovar.pl -format vcf4 "$f" > ./"$f".avinput  #run my code
     fi
    fi
done
```

#### Issue:

`echo $f` returns `/storage/testFiles/test.vcf`. How do I get only `test.vcf` while I iterate in `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the to use `basename`:

```
Synopsis

basename NAME [SUFFIX]    
basename OPTION 

Description

Print NAME with any leading directory components removed. If
specified, also remove a trailing SUFFIX.
```

Therefore:

```
$ basename /storage/testFiles/test.vcf
test.vcf
```

---

Also, if you need the opposite, you can use `dirname`:

```
$ dirname /storage/testFiles/test.vcf
/storage/testFiles
```